# Stack Overflow C variable position

Tags: c, stack-overflow

This is probably a simple question about StackOverflow but it's getting me crazy.

Let's take the example from wikipedia:

```
void foo (char *bar)
{

   char  c[28];        
   float myVar = 10.5;  

   printf("myVar value = %f\n", myVar);
   memcpy(c, bar, strlen(bar)); 

   printf("myVar value = %f\n", myVar);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
   foo("my string is too long !!!!! \x10\x10\xc0\x42");
   return 0;
}
```

If we run that piece of code(disabling all the compiler options) the output is:

```
myVar value = 10.500000
myVar value = 96.031372
```

Till this point everything is ok, Once memcpy reaches c[27], is gonna write on myVar space.

Now let's say that we change where the variable myVar is defined:

```
   float myVar = 10.5;  
   char  c[28];
```

The output remains the same, how is this possible? Is not suppose to write the overflow values inside the "Frame Pointer" space. Moreover, let's say I print the memory address of this variables, now the output is:

```
myVar value = 10.500000
myVar value = 10.500000
```

How is that possible, is this like quantum mechanic(just a joke)?Is not suppose to rewrite the "Frame Pointer" and crash the program?

Comment: It is *undefined* what it is supposed to do. That is, it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: There are a few duplicates of this kind of UB question.  Well, OK, thousands :(

Comment: Nothing is "supposed to crash a program".

Comment: Well, not crash, but when the Frame Pointer loads again it won't be the right  one

Comment: I am working for decades with systems *without* anything called "frame pointer". So what will it do on my system? Anyway, if you insist, you can look at the disassembly and/or run an instruction-level debugger to see what is going on.

Comment: I don't even understand the example. You changed the order to the same as it was and get the same output.

Comment: I'll do it, I'm asking this just to know what I'm missing here, the idea I have of the buffer overflow doesn't fit in here. I just want to know what really going on.

Comment: The two comments from @EugeneSh. should tell you what is really going on.

Comment: Agree with @EugeneSh. Its completely undefined behavior and depends on the compiler. On gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 here, its giving same response 10.50000 in both the scenarios.

Comment: Solved, it's the compiler, I've checked the assembly code and it doesn't matter where you declare the variable, it's always gonna be first the float and after the buffer. Maybe some optimization...

Comment: Although this is undefined behavior and every compiler might behave differently, on a lower level you should have about ~2Mb of reserved memory for the stack (not always true, but often true enough). Depending on your CPU, you are probably writing "ahead" of the stack (writing on your own reserved memory that you didn't claim just yet). This could be very bad if you were at the edge of the stack or if you used a different type of memory address scheme (there's a part in the CPU the translates your program's pointers into the actual memory address).

Answer (score 0):

Although this is undefined behavior and every compiler might behave differently, on a lower level it makes sense.

Depending on your OS and hardware, you should have about ~2Mb of reserved memory for the stack (not always true, but often true enough).

Depending on your system (and the CPU), you are probably writing "ahead" of the stack - you're writing on memory that was reserved for your own stack and your program's use, even though you didn't "claim" it just yet.

This could be very bad if you were at the edge of the stack or if your CPU used a different type of memory address resolution scheme (there's a part in the CPU the translates your program's pointers into the actual memory address)... especially on systems that have the stack memory going in a different direction or use a linked list for the stack.